# Webscraping: how to select a value (option) from a dropdown list on a webpage using VBA)

Tags: vba, parsing, dropdown, frame

On a website I was able to log in and then I was trying to select a value from a dropdown menu but I can't get any object containing the menu.

On concern is that the page seem to be using three frame windows-the dropdown menu is on one of the windows.

```
<label for="edit-multiple-form">...</label>
<select id="edit-multiple-form" name="NNN" class="form-select form-control required ajax-processed"> == $0
   <option value selected="selected">- Select -</option>
   <option value="1"> OPTION1 </option>
   <option value="2"> OPTION2 </option>
   <option value="3"> OPTION3 </option>
</select>
::after
</div>
```

VBA codes (updated):

```
Sub LogIn()

' ' ' ' ' 

'when Error
On Error GoTo Err_Clear

' ' ' ' ' 

'New HTML Document for the page
Dim IE3 As HTMLDocument
Set IE3 = IEBrowser.document

Dim elemSelect As IHTMLElement
Dim elemOption As IHTMLElement

Set elmSelect = IE3.getElementById("edit-multiple-wallet-form")
    Debug.Print elemSelect.innerText        
Set elemOption = elemSelect.getElementByTagName("option")  '@@ it gives me an error
If elemOption.Length > 0 Then
    Dim i, text
    For i = 0 To elemOption.lengh - 1
        text = text & elemOption.Item(i).innerText
    Next
    MsgBox "All pre elements text: " & text
End If
 
    ' ' ' ' ' 


Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then 
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If

End Sub
```

====================================================================

```
 'Got a new HTML document after log on the the first page
    Dim IE3 As HTMLDocument
    Set IE3 = IEBrower.document
    
'then tried several methods to get the object using the following commands 
IE3.document.querySelector("option")

IE3.all.NNN.value   'NNN is the name of the dropdown menu object

IE3.getElementsByID("edit-multiple-form)

IE3.getElementsByClass("form-select form-control required ajaz-processed")
```

==========================================================================

I was able to grab the dropdown menu object but still got an error at @@
What is wrong with it?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IE3.getElementById("edit-multiple-form")
```

This should return the *select* HTML element. Then you can further narrow by:

```
Set elemSelect = IE3.getElementById("edit-multiple-form")
Set elemOption = elemSelect.getElementsByTagName("option")
```

So then you can loop through (for i=0 to elemOption.length-1). Please note that getElementById does not have **s** in it, because it always returns exactly 1 item. Also, getElementsByClass is not a valid method, use getElementsByClassName instead.
The list of available methods are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Thanks !!
I was able to grab the object. but still I got an error at elemOption so I can't select "OPTION1"
What do you think the problem is?

Comment: It's pretty hard to say without seeing what you have tried. Next time please post the code which does not work. In the watch window check elemOption. It returns a collection of option HTML elements, so you have to select which one you want to work with. Check elemOption(0) there, that should be your first element.

Comment: Sorry, elemOption(0) will return the placeholder item. Use elemOption(1) to have OPTION1. Or if you want to check dynamically, use a for loop from 0 to elemOption.length-1 and check elemOption(i).innerText